# C++ Apache Module: Fails on `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE`

Tags: c++, linux, apache, c++11, shared-libraries

I'm trying to write an apache module in C++.

The basic module is compiling and linking fine in a .so.  When I attach it to the server all is ok.

Until I tried to use std::string.  Now I get the following error:

```
Cannot load mod_foo.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_foo.so: undefined symbol:
    _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
```

I assume this symbol is a mangled version of something std::string uses from the standard library.  Is there anyway add an option at compile or .so link time to indicate that the .so needs this library?

I compile my .o files as follows:

```
g++-4.7 -fpic -c -O3 -pthread -g -iquote .
   -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -Wall -Wextra
   -Werror -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fnon-call-exceptions
   -std=gnu++11 -x c++ -o ___.o ___
```

and link the .so as follows:

```
ld -Bshareable -o ___.so ___
```

Comment: I changed the link line to `g++-4.7 -shared -ldl -fPIC -rdynamic -g -O3  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fnon-call-exceptions -std=gnu++11 -o ___.so ___` and it works, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with `-lstdc++`

Using `g++` to link (instead of `gcc` or `ld`) does that automaticaly.

See [Compiling C++ programs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html) in the GCC manual:

> However, the use of `gcc` does not add the C++ library. `g++` is a program that calls GCC [...] and automatically specifies linking against the C++ library.

N.B. the options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -fnon-call-exceptions -std=gnu++11` have no effect when linking, those options only affect the compilation stage and are ignored during the link stage. During linking GCC just invokes the linker and only passes it options that are valid for linking.